# Intellij [Unresolved function or method ...]

Tags: javascript, intellij-idea

I have the following problem,

[image]

You can see that underscore is recognized by IDE with "filter" being yellow color. I have no idea why moment on the other hand turned purple and does not recognize "endOf" method. The code works but IDE kept giving me warnings.

Here is my library,
[image]
[image]

I installed **underscore** the same way I installed **moment**. What is the problem?

Comment: Is this javascript? Maybe edit your question to add that tag

Comment: This mean that your moment.js plugin not resolved here, it might be a web reference, so it is working.

Comment: hi can you elaborate more? As you can see moment is installed just like how underscore is installed in the libraries section?